# Stripe custom typography font

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, webfonts, cloud.typography

I have a cloud.typography font hosted on my webserver. When I try to link it to stripe using `stripe.elements()` my fonts do not show up and it defaults to Helvetica. I also do not receive any javascript error.

Here is my javascript code:

```
var elements = stripe.elements({
    fonts: [
        {
            cssSrc: 'localhost:8080/static/fonts/######/#################.css',
        },
    ],
});
var baseStyle = {
    fontFamily: 'Gotham Narrow A, Gotham Narrow B, sans-serif',
    fontSize: '16px',
    lineHeight: '1.5',
    fontWeight: '300',
    color: '#2d3138',
    '::placeholder': {
        color: '#8f95a3'
    }
};
var invalidStyle = {
    fontFamily: 'Gotham Narrow A',
    fontSize: '16px',
    lineHeight: '1.5',
    fontWeight: '300',
    color: '#e70000'
};
var style = {
    base: baseStyle,
    invalid: invalidStyle
};
var styles = {style: style};
var card = elements.create('cardNumber', styles);
```

If I try and link directly to typography using the css link it gives me, I receive the following error:

```
Failed to load https://cloud.typography.com/#######/#######/css/fonts.css: 
Redirect from 'https://cloud.typography.com/#######/#######/css/fonts.css' 
to 'https://myhostedwebsite.com/fonts/######/#################.css' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' 
is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have also tried importing my font as a font-family object.

```
var elements = stripe.elements({
    fonts: [
        {
            family: 'Gotham Narrow A',
            src: 'url(https://myhostedwebsite.com/fonts/######/#################.eot)',
            style: 'normal',
            weight: '300',
        },
    ],
});
```

Please help.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Latest version of Google Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

@Michael found out that he had to add stripe.com to in list of enabled domains on cloud.typography's project dashboard. Now the stripe elements are using the cloud.typography font. This is working when chrome was run with the --disable-web-security flag. These results are not working when using the chrome extension however.

---

Your error says:

```
Failed to load https://cloud.typography.com/#######/#######/css/fonts.css: 
Redirect from 'https://cloud.typography.com/#######/#######/css/fonts.css' 
to 'https://myhostedwebsite.com/fonts/######/#################.css' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' 
is therefore not allowed access.
```

Chrome doesn't support localhost for CORS request.

You can use the  [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) Chrome Extension to go around this issue. The extension will add the necessary HTTP Headers for CORS.

**OR**

Start chrome with the --disable-web-security flag

Comment: I ran google chrome with the --disable-web-security flag and tested my website. However, my fonts still did not show up. The error from the console is this: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`.

Comment: Did you try the chrome extension?

Comment: I did also try the chrome extension. I received this error: `The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'https://m.stripe.network' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`

Comment: Ohhh, okay, I got it working. Here's what I did. I had to add stripe.com to my list of enabled domains on cloud.typography's project dashboard. Now my stripe elements are using my cloud.typography font. This is working when I run chrome with the `--disable-web-security` flag. I cannot get these results when using the chrome extension however.

Comment: @Michael I was researching regarding that only. I'll update the answer accordingly for the community.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that demonstrates how to load a font from a third-party page (from another domain you don't necessarily control).

https://jsfiddle.net/5yz4z2yn/104/

You have to also import the webfont in the CSS.

`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower');`

Comment: This answer doesn't apply to my issue because cloud.typography is a subscription based webfont. I can't simply access the font with a url parameter. The procedure that cloud.typography uses to enable my purchased fonts is this: Cloud.typography generates hex codes for my webfonts and creates `.css` and `.eot` files. Then I download these fonts and move them into my website directory. Then when I publish my website, the fonts installation is confirmed by cloud.typography. Once the fonts have been confirmed, they become active. The `.css` files include all of the `@font-face{}` definitions.